# Disassembly of object file with offset from instruction pointer

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, object-files

The following example is provided in [this](https://www.apress.com/in/book/9781430266679) book.

There are two `.c` files and one `.h` file.

## main.c

```
#include "function.h"
extern int nCompletionStatus;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float x = 1.0;
    float y = 5.0;
    float z;

    z = add_and_multiply(x,y);
    nCompletionStatus = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

## function.h

```
#pragma once

#define FIRST_OPTION
#ifdef FIRST_OPTION
    #define MULTIPLIER (3.0)
#else
    #define MULTIPLIER (2.0)
#endif

float add_and_multiply(float x, float y);
```

## function.c

```
#include "function.h"
int nCompletionStatus = 0;

float add(float x, float y)
{
    float z = x + y;
    return z;
}

float add_and_multiply(float x, float y)
{
    float z = add(x,y);
    z *= MULTIPLIER;
    return z;
}
```

To produce the `.o` files, the following command is provided:

`gcc -c function.c main.c`

Then, to view the contents of `main.o`, we have:

`objdump -D -M intel main.o`.

The author in his book lists the (snippets of) content of the `objdump` output thus focussing on the unresolved external reference in `main.o` to `add_and_multiply(,)` and the `extern`ed `nCompletionStatus`:

```
27: 89 04 24             mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
2a: e8 fc ff ff ff       call   2b <main + 0x2b>    ;//highlighted (a) by author
2f: d9 5c 24 1c          fstp   DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c]
33: c7 05 00 00 00 00 01 mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x0,0x1 ;//highlighted (b) by author
```

On my machine, which is slightly different from what the author has produced, I get the following output of `objdump` (relevant parts only):

```
3c: e8 00 00 00 00       call   41 <main+0x41>;//Equivalent to highlight (a) of author?
41: 66 0f 7e c0          movd   eax,xmm0
45: 89 45 fc             mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
48: c7 05 00 00 00 00 01 mov    DWORD PTR [rip+0x0],0x1        # 52 <main+0x52>;//equivalent to highlight (b) of author?
```

My questions are indicated as comments above. That is, how is the output on my machine (running `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10)`) equivalent to what the author reports?

In particular, in the author's version, in highlight (b), `ds:` seems to be accessed, while in my version, some offset from the `rip` register seems to be in place. How are they equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book you refer to is using 32 bit assembly while your compiler emits 64 bit assembly.  Pass `-m32` to `gcc` to compile your C code into 32 bit machine code instead.  Also consider using `-d` instead of `-D` for `objdump` as the former only tries to disassemble sections that are known to contain machine code.

Comment: Let me try that. Although, I am not necessarily trying to match my output with what the author reports. My question was more related to how in 32 bit, highlight (b) seems to refer to the data segment (?), while in 64 bit, it is some offset off the instruction pointer.

Comment: @Tryer Every memory access is relative to some segment.  But that's a red herring as segmentation is not used in modern operating systems.  The assembly likes to include the name of the segment for absolute memory accesses, but I don't really know why.  In 64 bit mode, a new `rip` relative addressing mode exists which is used instead of absolute addressing.  It boils down to the same thing, except your code is now position-independent.

Comment: IIUC, in the author's version, the code segment (highlight(b)) refers to the data segment which is elsewhere in the object file. In my version, the offset from the instruction pointer seems to be 0. Now, will not this line be reached for execution when the instruction pointer is on line 48? then, an offset of 0 points again to line 48 in the code segment itself. So, what is confusing for me is how in my version (64 bit), any reference at all is made to the data segment.

Comment: The offset is 0 because you are inspecting an object file where the locations of variables and functions haven't been filled in yet.  If you inspect an executable program (i.e. after linking), then the linker has already filled in all the relocations and the numbers are going to make sense.  The sections and segments of an ELF binary do not correspond to x86 segments.  Do not confuse these two and try to forget that the latter exist for a while.

Comment: @Tryer In fact, on normal x86 operating systems, all four basic x86 segment registers are set to refer to the same segment bases, so it doesn't matter which of the segments you use when referring to a datum in memory.  That said, the segment registers fs and gs are some times used for special purposes, namely, for thread-local storage.